# Azure Data Factory: Repeating First Page while Fetching Data from API Pagination

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am facing an issue while using `Azure Data Factory` to fetch data from an `API` that supports pagination. It successfully reads and fetches all the data from the first page, but when it tries to move on to the next page, it repeats the process for page one again and again till the request failed. The `hasMore` in the metadata is True till the pages end in the API. The details are given in the screenshot.

[image: API metadata]

As a result, I'm unable to retrieve the complete data from the `API`. I have checked my pipeline configuration and the pagination settings, but everything seems to be in order. I suspect there might be an issue with the way `Azure Data Factory` handles pagination or with my configuration. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem.

I have used the Pagination rules `EndCondition` in  `Azure data factory`. The `EndCondition` we have provided is as `$hasMore`=false then the API should end and we should get all the data till the end page. But it does not move to the next page.

[image: ADF Pagination Rule implemented]

Comment: can you please add your URL ?

Comment: how will you paginate the  URL?

Comment: I have used the pagination rules in ADF, as the end page was not mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***We must use EndCondition if the variables are in `AbsoluteUrl` ,`QueryParameters` or `Headers` the end variable is not pre-defined, and the end condition depends on the Response of API*.**

You must first paginate the URL using the `AbsoluteUrl`/`QueryParameters`/`Headers` with the `Range` or `nexpagelink` URL.

- Next, set the following end condition rule:

```
"EndCondition:$.meta.page.hasmore":"Const:False"
```

[image: insert description of image here]

when the value of a particular node in the response is a user-defined const value, the pagination should be stopped.

Visit this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#example-4variables-are-in-absoluteurlqueryparametersheaders-the-end-variable-is-not-pre-defined-and-the-end-condition-is-based-on-the-response) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Instead of using an absolute URL, I have used a query parameter. Additionally, I have left the end range null as I am unaware of the offset of the page.